# Wordpress customized login form if empty redirect link issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am using `wp_login_form()` to create a login form on the home page.

One issue is that the form will redirect to `wp-login.php` if the user/pass is empty. I want it to direct to customized page, so I use the following code. It works, but, I cannot access to `wp-login.php` anymore; if I type `www.mysite/wp-login.php`, it will redirect it to the empty. How can I fix this?

```php
<?php
 function verify_username_password( $user, $username, $password ) {  
         $login_page  = home_url( '/login/' );  
         if( empty($username)  || empty($password) ) {  
             wp_redirect( $login_page . "?login=empty" );  
             exit;  
         }  
       }


     add_filter( 'authenticate', 'verify_username_password', 1, 3);  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to check the form has been submitted. 
The form should have a submit button, hopefully with a name. For example, if it contains an input with type submit and name="submit" then you can check if(isset($_POST['submit'])) to be sure it has been submitted before redirecting the user to another page. 
Note that Wordpress might have it's own function for getting input values from get/post which you should use if it does.

Let me know how you go.